How to make sure RetroFit2 won't serialize a single string being a parameter of POST request into extra double quote? How to unserialize it if so?
I got such interface using RetroFit2:
package com.somePackage.client.web.business.feature.control;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

import com.somePackage.client.web.business.feature.entity.featureModel;
import com.somePackage.client.web.business.feature.entity.featureExtensiveModel;

public interface someFeatureApi {

    @GET("someFeature/{deviceId}")
    Call<featureModel> getDeviceId(@Path("deviceId") String deviceId);

    @POST("someFeature/deviceData")
    Call<featureExtensiveModel> getDeviceData(@Body String deviceId);
}

What if I'd like to send just a single string using POST method?
But the deviceId must be specifically String, because it's passed as string to this getDeviceData method somewhere else.
And when I set the deviceId type inside of getDeviceData method to some other type, like my example DeviceIdType Object type, as recommend in an answer to question retrofit request body is adding double quotes in @Body parameter instead of String, the IntelliJ IDEA linter shows warning that it's potentially error producing, because types don't match, because somewhere else in some class, this getDeviceData method, as a I already mentioned before, is called with deviceId parameter being passed as String.
Honestly, I haven't tried to use solution with object type (example DeviceIdType type), but won't it trigger linter also?
